# Download all Curiosity photos?

Tags: rovers, curiosity, photography

I'm interested in downloading all of the Curiosity rover photos. Is there some sort of automated way to do this?

Comment: http://mars.jpl.nasa.gov/msl/multimedia/raw/ - have you tried [wgetting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget)?

Comment: @DeerHunter: This will probably produce tons of unrelated junk, especially that the actual images reside on a different path than the document root (but same host) you linked, and 4 clicks deep from it, so plain exclusion of parent directory won't suffice. I'm pretty good with wget but I'd have a problem thinking up a syntax that will get all raw images from the link provided and not grab videos, 3D images and such in the process.

Comment: @SF. http://www.unmannedspaceflight.com/index.php?s=&showtopic=7375&view=findpost&p=188520

Answer (score 9):

Source: http://www.unmannedspaceflight.com/index.php?s=&showtopic=7375&view=findpost&p=188520

**MSL IMAGE RETRIEVAL TOOLS**

Links from the [Curiosity Image Retrieval Tools](http://www.unmannedspaceflight.com/index.php?showtopic=7408) Thread.

```
Please note that we do not guarantee any of the programs listed.
They are links provided by or programs/website developed by members.
Please use them at your caution.
```

- A [shell script](http://paranoid.dechengst.nl/files/MSLget.sh) that allows you to download all images from a given sol
- [Curiosity RAW Get](http://www.unmannedspaceflight.com/index.php?act=attach&type=post&id=27458)
- [Star Downloader](http://www.stardownloader.com/)
- [Mars Ogler](http://mars-ogler.com/) Check out the *grid* view in the menu options.
- [DownloadThemAll plugin for Firefox](http://www.downthemall.net/)
- Automatically updated RAW images online - [link to external website](http://msl-raw-images.com/)
- A basic web interface listing images for a particular Sol - [link to external website](http://curiositymsl.com/rawlist)
- Web interface to the raw images - [link to external website](http://curiositymsl.com/table/view)

Answer (score 5):

I hope the original Questioneer is not still looking for the imagedata. But for people who are looking at the moment, I could give you another website to retrieve Nasa Mars Rover and more Raw Images:

https://pds-imaging.jpl.nasa.gov

It is really difficult to find this tool with the help of google, but it is worthy.

The only small Issue, the website creates a shell script with `wget` commands for every image selected. For the Data I downloaded once it took me 6 days in total because 40 GB of Images with a max size of 2 MB and downloading them step-by-step with single `wget`s takes some time.

EDIT: The Website is correct but the actual tool is the image atlas which could be found on the left site.

Comment: It's great when a new user revives an old question by adding a new and (presumably) helpful solution!